FCC regulations stipulate that personal electronic devices must be set to airplane mode during flight. Are there any exceptions?
Reflecting on a flight I took recently, where the crew allowed us to use WiFi even while our devices were in airplane mode, got me wondering about the specifics of FCC regulations regarding electronic devices on planes. Traditionally, we're told to switch all devices to airplane mode to avoid interference with navigation systems, but it seems like there's some flexibility with newer technology and updated aircraft systems.
So, my question to fellow travelers is: Have you encountered any exceptions to the standard rule of setting devices to airplane mode during flights? How do airlines communicate these exceptions?

Airplane mode only affects communications between your devices and "public" cell towers (because, as you say it's and FCC rule, not an FAA one). Wi-Fi works and has always worked with airplane mode on, as you're only connecting to the hotspot on the plane itself (which internally uses satellite to get internet access).

@ComputerUser121212 I’m not quite sure this is true. When airplane mode was introduced all wireless communication was shut down, including cellular, WiFi and BT. It was later progressively relaxed to allow BT, Wifi and then cellular, with lots of variations between countries, airlines, phases of flight…

@ComputerUser121212 note that there are also FAA rules: 14 C.F.R § 91.21 actually prohibits use of all electronic devices on board, with or without wireless, unless they are among a very short list of devices (hearing aids, pacemakers…) or the airline deems it safe.

@ComputerUser121212 every phone I've had disables WiFi (and Bluetooth and NFC? I use them rarely so I don't know) when airplane mode is activated, requiring the user to turn them back on if they want to use them during the flight.

@phoog My Samsung Galaxy S21 doesn't turn off bluetooth when airplane mode is turned on--I use it for a blood glucose sensor so I leave BT on. Turning on airplane mode does turn off wi-fi though.

Devices turn off Wi-Fi, but it can be re-enabled, in contrast to mobile data or calls, which can't (without turning airplane mode off).

@jcaron That is true but modern airlines consider virtually every device to be safe. Airplane mode is still mandated by FCC though.

@phoog Most newer Android phones turn off most radios (I believe NFC is excluded from this due to the very low power involved (single digit mW) and the fact that the 13.56 MHz band it uses is not used in aviation), but let you optionally turn WiFi and Bluetooth back on after activating airplane mode (though they will often remember the state of the WiFi and Bluetooth radios when you disabled airplane mode, and copy that for the next time you activate it).

I worked in the air-to-ground telephone industry back in the late 1980s-early 1990s.  At this time analog cellular was just becoming popular.  It's my understanding that the initial objection to using cellphones on aircraft was not interference with the aircraft, but with the cellular system.  Cellular systems rely on frequency re-use between nonadjacent cells, and a cellphone on an airplane at altitude can occupy a single channel over an entire metro region.  Nowadays cellphones are all digital but the fact that a single phone is hitting dozens of cells would still be problematic.

Airplane mode in my iPhone turns off all radios, including the receive-only GPS.  But I could turn on WiFi which enabled the GPS (which has no directly accessible control).  I used to use a dedicated GPS device to record the flight path, and on one flight, the crew would not accept my explanation that the device did NOT transmit.

My Android phone has GPS (and probably other GNSS) enabled even in airplane mode.  Theoretically a receiving-only antenna still interacts with the EM radiation it detects, but I am skeptical of the claim this is enough to cause a problem for the cockpit.

@gerrit: I do not think it will cause problem, but we are missing one important fact: there are various crappy phones (possibly damaged) which do weird things (interferences on all kind of frequencies). (and it is never my phone)! So airlines have simple rules. OTOH they know many people will not follow them. If (when( it would be a problem, they will increase screening (like they did for baggages because nobody was following dangerous good prohibition, and it caused problems).

Airplane mode can allow Bluetooth (so you can use wireless headphones, among other things) and Wifi. On Apple devices you have to manually re-enable them individually once the Airplane mode is initiated.
It's up to the airline whether they allow BT and Wifi, but Cellular is always off when the device is in Airplane mode.
The maximum transmit power levels for Wifi and BT are something like 30x lower than for cellular. It's aggravated for cellular in an aircraft because the phone cranks up the transmit power when it can't find a cell tower. That said, I bet in a full wide-body flight there are an average of at least several phones left in cellular mode.
Since some airlines have decided to skip the expense of installing seat-back screens for entertainment and deliver what  they have over Wifi, and some airlines make money or differentiate themselves by offering some internet connectivity, there is an incentive for them to ensure the devices can be safely used, and to allow it.
As to how they might communicate situations when it is not allowed, here is a photo from Reddit:


I just tested it on my Android phone, when I switch to airplane mode both data and wifi switch off but I can switch wifi back on.

@Willeke Now turn airplane mode off and back on again - you might find it remembers that those are allowed in airplane mode. Depends on the phone and exact software, but that's what mine does.

@Doc Mine restores the BT but not Wifi. The latter has to be re-enabled each time. I suppose it might do something different if it couldn't detect a Wifi or cellular signal.

Bar graphs are prohibited, one shall only plot using line graphs! :D (Also, I haven't flown since 2019, but this is the first time I've seen a prohibition on bottles; and what does the loose word "WATER" here refere to?)

@gerrit That's clearly a liquor bottle. They don't like it when folks start in on the duty-free during the flight. As to the 'Water', it refers to the aircraft floating suspiciously buoyantly on the water and the passengers calmly exiting through A, B, B again and A again (to rafts?).  People in the water holding each other in rings or hungry sharks circling?
